# How to pass function as parameters

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I have a function that receives a vector and sum all the elements.

```
(def rec
  (fn [numbers acc]
    (if (empty? numbers)
      acc
      (recur (rest numbers) (+ acc (first numbers))))))
(prn (rec [1 2 3] 0))
```

But instead of calling the function "+" I want to pass the operation as parameter, it means, I want to pass a function as parameter and then call the function.

I tried:

```
(def rec
  (fn [f numbers acc]
    (if (empty? numbers)
      acc
      (recur (rest numbers) (f acc (first numbers))))))
(prn (rec + [4 2 1] 0))
```

But it does not work, I know there are better ways to sum numbers in a vector, but I'm starting with functional, so it is important to do this kind of exercise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recur with the same arguments as the parameter vector, in this case:

```
(recur f (rest numbers) (f acc (first numbers))))))
```

(btw, it's standard to use `defn` for defining functions, `(defn f[x] ... )` is more concise than `(def f (fn [x] ...)))`

Comment: I just realized that. Thank you so much Diego. And thanks for the advice about the function definition. Is the identation correct?

Comment: @renanreismartins From an indentation/alignment/formatting perspective your code is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

More ideomatic Clojure would be using reduce here, I think

```
(defn rec [f numbers acc]
  (reduce f acc numbers))

(rec + [1 2 3] 0)
# 6
```

Comment: As you can see, `rec` function do just the same as `reduce` but with changed attributes order

Answer (score 0):

*Factoring*

In your

```
(def rec
  (fn [numbers acc]
    (if (empty? numbers)
      acc
      (recur (rest numbers) (+ acc (first numbers))))))
```

... you can push the accumulator `acc` beneath the surface of `rec`:

```
(defn rec [numbers]
  (loop [ns numbers, acc 0]
    (if (empty? ns)
      acc
      (recur (rest ns) (+ acc (first ns))))))
```

For example,

```
(rec + [1 3])
; 4
```

If you want to pass *the operation* as a parameter, the convention is that calling it with *no* arguments gives its identity: the value which returns the other argument when it is applied to two.

Thus

```
(+) ; => 0
(*) ; => 1
```

So we can write your parameterized `rec` as

```
(defn rec [op numbers]
  (loop [ns numbers, acc (op)]
    (if (empty? ns)
      acc
      (recur (rest ns) (op acc (first ns))))))
```

This is almost how `reduce` works, though not quite as elegantly, IMO.